# Will file be closed after "open(file_name, 'w+').write(somestr)"

Tags: python

I'm new to python.

I wonder if I write:

```
open('/tmp/xxx.txt', 'w+').write('aabb')
```

Will the file be still opened or closed?

In another word, what's the difference between the above and

```
with open('/tmp/xxx.txt', 'w+') as f:
  f.write('aabb')
```

Comment: Not sure why this is downvoted, it's a clearly stated and on-topic question.

Comment: @flornquake might be because it lacks research. I'm certain the official documentation covers these cases.

Comment: @ŁukaszRogalski How can you conclude that this question is a duplicate of that one?

Comment: @vaultah: [It does.](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/)

Comment: @ŁukaszRogalski, @Jan, `with` is a mere half of the question.

Comment: @vaultah, how does the question you've linked to addresses the reference counting questions?

Comment: @zneak please read the first two answers.

Comment: @vaultah, none of the answers say anything about the lifetime of a variable that isn't captured.

Answer (score 2):

The file might stay open.

Keep in mind that it **will** be automatically closed upon garbage collection or software termination but it's a bad practice to count on it as exceptions, frames or even delayed GC might keep it open.

Also, you might lose data if the program terminated unexpectedly and you don't `flush()` it.

---

In many distributions of python, where the GC is different (PyParallel for example) it might cause a big problem.

Even in CPython, it might still stay open in case of frame reference for example. Try running this:

```
import sys
glob_list = []

def func(*args, **kwargs):
    glob_list.append((args, kwargs))
    return func

sys.settrace(func)

open('/tmp/xxx.txt', 'w+').write('aabb')
```

Comment: Specifcally, in cpython, it will likely be immediately closed.  In other implementations of Python with differing GC semantics, it may stay open (and possibly unwritten) for quite some time.